# HTML mask url with another url

Tags: html, frames, html-frames

I have two domains, one is a .com domain and the other is a .ca domain. My current host (on the .com domain) does not allow me to register .ca domains, so i registered one with Netfirms. Netfirms will not let me change the namespace to that of my other host, so i am in need of a way to show one url, but view a different url.

For example:
user visits www.googleabcdefg.ca.

www.googleabcdefg.ca displays the information of www.google.com without actually redirecting the user to www.google.com. Also when the user clicks a link the www.googleabcdefg.ca address remains and does not go to www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second domain's provider doesn't allow you to change DNS entries?

In that case, the easiest way may be to change to a provider who does.

For that to work, your current web host needs to support external domains pointing their DNS records to the web server that your package is on: Talk to them to find out whether they do. Seeing as they don't offer the .ca TLD, one could expect them to allow you to buy it elsewhere.

Comment: It turns out that since my main host does not support.ca i am unable to set the namespace, if they did support .ca then the change would be allowed. I am instead using frames like the ones mentioned on this site url
http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/URL-masking.php
to do the job, it is kind of a hack but it seems to work

Comment: @Dustin ah, okay. You could still ask them whether they're willing to add the domain manually - some providers might do it, some not.

Comment: no such luck, but i appreciate the help. Thanks a bunch Pekka :)